# default argument mismatch in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, default-parameters

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Bar
{
public:
    void foo(bool b = false, std::string name = "");
};

void Bar::foo(bool b, std::string name)
{
    if (!b)
    {
       std::cout << "b is false" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
       std::cout << "b is true" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Bar myBar;
    myBar.foo("bla");
    return 0;
}
```

I guess C++ is not broken, but can anyone please explain why the output is true? I am working on VS 2010 but I also checked in ideone which runs gcc

Comment: I want to point out @half of the answers below that "bla" is a `const char[4]`, which decays to a `const char *`, which can then assume `true` for not being a null pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is implicitly casting the first parameter, a `char const[4]`, to `bool`, and results in `true`.

It's equivalent to

```
myBar.foo((bool)"bla");
```

which is also equivalent to

```
myBar.foo((bool)"bla", "");
```

Comment: The first *argument* is a `char const[4]`, not a `char const*`.

Comment: The key point is that C++ does not have positional parameters, and default parameters always have to follow explicitly passed parameters. Boost.Parameter gives some syntax to make life a little easier.

Comment: @rhalbersma: I don't know about "making life easier". It's ugly as heck and unreadable, IMHO.

Comment: @Xeo For policy classes with many defaulted template parameters, Boost.Parameter is not so bad. For function parameters I tend to agree with you.

Comment: Which is, in the end, the equivalent of `"bla" != NULL`.  (The authors of the proposal which added `bool` to C++ wanted to deprecate these implicit conversions, but the committee didn't follow them there.)

Answer (score 1):

Because the `"bla"` is a `char const[4]`, which decays to `const char*`, and is cast to a bool. Since it's value is not `0`, the cast takes the value `true`. A simpler example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha; // print bools nicely
  bool b = "Hello";
  std::cout << b << "\n";

}
```

produces

> true

Answer (score 0):

Bool parameter convert "bla" to true.
You need to change order of your parameters.